# How to identify the first execution of a Lambda version at runtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to run some code only on the first execution of a Lambda version. (NB: I'm not referring to a cold start scenario as this will occur more than once).

*computeInstanceInvocationCount* is unfortunately reset to 0 upon every cold start.

*functionVersion* is an available property but unless I store this in memory outside the lambda I cannot calculate if it is indeed the first execution.

Is it possible to deduce this based on runtime values in event or context? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Store state in DynamoDB, for example use the Lambda function/version as a key and keep a count of invocations in an atomic counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of knowing if this is the first time that a Lambda has ever run from any information passed into the Lambda.

You would have to include functionality to check elsewhere by setting a flag or parameter there, remember though that multiple copies of the Lambda could be invoked at the same time so any data store for this would presumably need to be transactional to ensure that it occurs only once.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity do you know if it's possible for two cold starts to happen simulataneously? I'm thinking by placing the logic only when isColdStart is true, it will remove the transactional requirement

Comment: Technically its possible if you have high traffic volumes, Lambdas are distributed on Firecracker Micro vms. Additionally if you have very little traffic you will find that the function itself may have multiple cold starts throughout its lifetime. Finally if a Lambda node fails or an AZ fails then another MicroVM will be used (resulting in another cold start)

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can try is to use [AWS parameter store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

On every deployment update the parameter store value with

```
{"version":"latest","is_firsttime":true}
```

So run the below command after deployment

```
aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id demo --secret-string  '{"version":"latest","is_firsttime":true}'
```

So this is something that we need to make sure before deployment.

Now we can set logic inside the lambda, in the demo we will look into `is_firsttime` only.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'),
    region = "us-west-2",
    secretName = "demo",
    secret,
    decodedBinarySecret;
var client = new AWS.SecretsManager({
    region: region
});
client.getSecretValue({SecretId: secretName}, function(err, data) {

 secret = data.SecretString;
        secret=JSON.parse(secret)
        if ( secret.is_firsttime == true)
            {
             console.log("lambda is running first time")
            //  any init operation here
            // init completed, now we are good to set back it `is_firsttime` to false
            var params = {
                Description: "Init completeed, updating value at date or anythign", 
                SecretId: "demo",
                SecretString : '[{ "version" : "latest", "is_firsttime": false}]'
               };
               client.updateSecret(params, function(err, data) {
                 if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                 else     console.log(data);           // successful response
               });
               
            }
        else{
            console.log("init already completed");
            // rest of logic incase of not first time
        }
})
```

This is just a demo code that will work in a non-lambda environment, adjust it accordingly.

Expected response for first time

```
{
  ARN: 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:12345:secret:demo-0Nlyli',
  Name: 'demo',
  VersionId: '3ae6623a-1111-4a41-88e5-12345'
}
```

Second time

```
init already completed
```